# Is it possible to hide completely unrelated jobs?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

This is an example of a completely unrelated job for me:

[image]

I am sorry, but I have no intention of ever working with Linux and I have no idea what [etl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etl) is. Why do I have to see these jobs? I end up hiding most jobs so I'm at least shown [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)/[asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) jobs.

Ideally, I don't want to have to see any job that does not contain one of the tags I'm interested in and no job that contains one of the tags I don't want to work with, regardless of the other tags:

[image]

Comment: When did you add your preferences for tags you won't want to work with?

Comment: @HoriaComan For [tag:linux], a day ago or something like that, the rest of the tags are weeks/months old.

Comment: And when did you see the ad? There's _a delay_ between when you make a change like that and when it's picked up by the system which serves the ad. So it's quite possible to still see ads for tag **X** for a short while after you've disliked it. If it's later than a day _then_ I'd worry.

Comment: The ad in the screenshot is from around 5 minutes before posting this question. The question is mostly to ask whether I can hide jobs that do not contain liked tags, rather than hide disliked ones

Comment: Oh. Then the answer's no on that. We don't consider liked tags at all when selecting these jobs (though we do consider them in other contexts). That's basically a product decision.

Comment: My initial thought was "why would they not require a positive match, that would be great!" And moments later, I realized it's pretty unlikely for a company to block their own ads until users create a customized whitelist filter. Especially when their target audience is very good at finding and exploiting loopholes.

Comment: @HoriaComan So... instead of being able to white-list what I want, I need to black-list everything else? That sucks, really. That's why I tagged with [meta-tag:feature-request]

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto added some more context to my answer, which would not fit in a comment. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That *is* strange. When looking at what jobs to show you we discard those with tags you don't want to work with.

I'll look if there's a bug somewhere.

---

Adding a bit more context after the discussion on the question.
The idea is that the "tech you prefer not to work with" acts as a hard filter for jobs. Those that have at least one of the tags you don't like won't be shown to you. The "tech you want to work with" doesn't do anything at all for the job ads. It does for other things though.

Getting this right is a bit tricky I think. It's a decision between showing you jobs which might not be relevant (by ignoring tech you like) or not showing you a really good match (by using tech you like). The latter case will act as an extremely aggressive filter on jobs. For example, if you like c#, but an employer tagged their job with asp.net, we'd not show you that job. Even though chances are that it's a very good fit for you.

So the decision we made was to not use these tags, because we think a missed opportunity is worse than the annoyance of seeing *some* bad jobs. We *do* try to show you good jobs for you, and the tags they have are just one part of what goes into the decision.

The same should be said about evaluating the job yourself. The tags are just a very slim summary . For example "java robotics" can describe an exciting position building the AI unit for helper robots at Good People Ltd, as much as it can describe building payroll software at Killer Robots Inc. There's also plenty of cool ones out there with badly chosen tags.

Finally, it's not a given we won't *ever* use these things. While we won't probably implement a hard filter, giving more weight to the tech you like is definitely on the radar.

Comment: Thanks, that made a lot of sense, hadn't really thought of that

Comment: Where could we read up on what things like these tags influence? Until now, I've assumed that these tags are only for displaying